# Audiio fiiles inside an iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, audio, fileshare

Is there a way inside an iOS Swift app of mine, to access the sound files I already have available in my itunes library on the same device?

Browsing the net I came accross something called File-Sharing and the UIFileSharingEnabled key, but that does not seem to be quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+access+iTunes+library).

Comment: OK, I am using this as a base for further investigations.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch29.html

Answer (score 1):

The files? I’m not sure.. if so only those you downloaded or bought on iTunes. For access to Apple Music you probably want to look into [MusicKit](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/).

However, there’s a way to get MediaItems via `MPMediaPickerController` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediapickercontroller))